# Перезагрузка страницы после "return Content();"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Новичок в этом деле.
Разрабатываю сайт с помощью ASP.NET MVC. Делаю странице с входом в аккаунт.
Код:

```
<div class="login">
    <form class="form__login" name="Login">
        <div class="exeption-textarea" style="color: red;"></div>
        <textarea class="input" name="login" placeholder="Введите логин" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
        <textarea class="input" name="password" placeholder="Введите пароль" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
        <button class="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Login.js"></script>
```

```
function Login() {
    var formData = new FormData(document.forms.Login);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Login/login?login=" + formData.get("login") + "&password=" + formData.get("password"),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "Неверный логин или пароль!") {
                $(".exeption-textarea").append(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

После того, как я вызываю `return Content("Неверный логин или пароль!");` в контроллере, у меня в "exeption-textarea" добавляется соответствующий текст, но после этого страница просто перезагружается, после  чего все изменения убираются.
Как можно избежать перезагрузки страницы в данный момент?

Comment: `return false` сделайте в конце функции, чтобы предотвратить дефолтную отправку формы

Comment: зы: если вы этот код пишите по какому-то учебнику или статье, то лучше смените источник знаний.

Comment: Поддержу другого комментатора, пишите ASP.NET Core MVC на .NET 5 или .NET 6, в обеих версиях предлагается установка стандартной системы Идентификации, пример рабочего кода MVC для .NET 5, с реализаций Идентификации и Авторизации Пользователей по Ролям вот [тут](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Rocky).